# How do I change the style of a cell in a column in an HTML table based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, htmlcollection

I have an HTML table where the rows and cells are created dynamically using JavaScript. I need to change the style (background colour) of the cell with the lowest and highest value within each column. How do I achieve this? I have given each `<td>` tag within the same column a class.

```
<table id="table">
    <thead id="thead">
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>col6</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">

        //DYNAMICALLY ADDED TR AND TDS ADDED HERE

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In order to have all the children of one of your columns you can use the `Element.children` property. After you can iterate on this collection to get the value of each child and then compare each value to determine the maximum and the minimum value.

```
const myElement = document.getElementById('thead');
for (const column of myElement.children) {
  var maximum = 0;
  var maximumElement;
  var minimum = 0;
  var minimumElement;
  for (const cell of column.children) {
    if (cell.value > maximum)
      maximumElement = cell;
    if (cell.value < minimum)
      minimumelement = cell;
  }
  maximumElement.style.backgroundcolor = 'green';
  minimumElement.style.backgroundcolor = 'red';
}
```

I hope it's can help you